# Is there any way of changing current user in PHP (Ubuntu)?

Tags: php

Recently I've been looking for a PHP/Linux shell script that would change current working user from "www-data" to the other one.

Since I tried running this service: http://cfgfactory.com/images/servers_hire.png which is basically starting a "call of duty 4" server it worked all fine since I realized there's a bug in the call of duty 4 server that let's you download ANY file from the server I tried downloading ../../../var/www/config.php and that worked just fine... So I setup a new user for this service and that's why I need a way of changing user

That's how I start the server:

```
function start_cod4($mod,$port,$id){


    $cod4_dir = '/home/bartz/cod4/';
    if(getcwd() != $cod4_dir){
            chdir($cod4_dir);   
    }

    $run = array(
    'sv_hostname' => 'Hire & Play No.'.$id.' by ^1CFG^7Factory.com/host/ - Free game server hiring !',
    'rcon_password' => substr(md5(uniqid()),0,5),
    'g_password' => 'war'.substr(md5(uniqid()),0,3)
    );

    exec('nohup ./cod4_lnxded +set s_num='.$id.' +set net_port '.$port.' +set dedicated 2 +set fs_game mods/'.$mod.' +set sv_punkbuster 1 +set sv_hostname "'.$run['sv_hostname'].'" +set rcon_password "'.$run['rcon_password'].'" +set g_password "'.$run['g_password'].'" +set promod_mode match_mr10 +set g_gametype sd +map '.random_map().' > /dev/null 2>&1 &');
    return $run;

}
```

So basically I need a PHP or either SH script that would change current working user to another.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Changing the user seems like the wrong idea, I just don't know the right solution.

Comment: Why can't you start the CoD server under a different name in the first place?  Is your script what starts the server?

Comment: First, you probably shouldn't be using a webpage to start local services. Second, `sudo` is the command to run things as another user. It's not just for root!

Comment: Only registered users can create a new server, also it will be automatically turned off by cron task if there are no players for more than 5 minutes.

Comment: Look at sudo, it would allow you to login as another user.  Though it will require the password of the user if you aren't root.  Though as the others have said, be very careful, one lax security check and people could gain access to an account on your system, never a good thing.  You might have better luck with this over at serverfault.com

Answer (score 2):

You cannot change from one regular user to another on Unix systems. it'd be complete gutting of the security systems if all it took to impersonate another was `posix_setuid(id of victim)`.

You'd have to start your PHP script as root, then do a [`posix_seteuid()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.posix-seteuid.php) to assume the other ID.

A safer alternative is to run the script as a regular user, and then exec() a call out to sudo to run your CoD startup script.